# Dependency Injection error: Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate, while class is registered

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, blazor

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'BotLab.me.Services.StatisticBackgroundService' while attempting to activate 'BotLab.Net.Controllers.StatsController'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ThrowHelperUnableToResolveService(Type type, Type requiredBy)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean hasDefaultValue, Object key)
   at lambda_method340(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[])
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
```

ошибка когда обращаюсь к контроллеру

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StatsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IStatisticRepository _statisticRepository;
    
    private readonly StatisticBackgroundService _statisticBackgroundService;
    
    public StatsController(IStatisticRepository statisticRepository, StatisticBackgroundService statisticBackgroundService)
    {
        _statisticRepository = statisticRepository;
        _statisticBackgroundService = statisticBackgroundService;
    }
    // POST api/<StatsController>
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post([FromBody] List<Statistic> value, [FromQuery] string key)
    {
        if (value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) && key == "HelloWorld!!!12345")
        {
            _statisticRepository.Add(value);
            foreach (var item in value)
            {
                _statisticBackgroundService.AddStaticBd(item);
            }
            return Ok();
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

вот Background сервис:

```
public class StatisticBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<StatisticBackgroundService> _logger;
    private readonly IStatisticRepository _statisticRepository;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public StatisticBackgroundService(
        ILogger<StatisticBackgroundService> logger, 
        IStatisticRepository statisticRepository,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _statisticRepository = statisticRepository;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var stats = _statisticRepository.Get();
            if (stats.Count == 0)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1);
                continue;
            }
            foreach ( var statistic in stats)
            {
                await AddStaticBd(statistic);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Queued Hosted Service is stopping.");

        await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
    }

    public async Task AddStaticBd(Statistic statisticDTO)
    {
        try
        {
            using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            var st = await db.KeyStat.OrderByDescending(x => x.Created)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => 
                                        x.Key == statisticDTO.ApiKey 
                                        && x.Ip == statisticDTO.Ip
                                        && x.SoftId == statisticDTO.SoftId);
            if (st == null)
            {
                await db.KeyStat.AddAsync(new KeyStat
                {
                    Bad= statisticDTO.Bad,
                    Good= statisticDTO.Good,
                    Ip= statisticDTO.Ip,
                    Key=statisticDTO.ApiKey,
                    SoftId= statisticDTO.SoftId
                });
            }
            else
            {
                if(st.Created < DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(3))
                {
                    await db.KeyStat.AddAsync(new KeyStat
                    {
                        Bad = statisticDTO.Bad,
                        Good = statisticDTO.Good,
                        Ip = statisticDTO.Ip,
                        Key = statisticDTO.ApiKey,
                        SoftId = statisticDTO.SoftId
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    st.Good += statisticDTO.Good;
                    st.Bad += statisticDTO.Bad;
                }
            }
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "AddStaticBd: {ex}", ex.Message);
            _statisticRepository.Add(new List<Statistic> { statisticDTO });
        }
    }
}
```

как регистрирую:
`builder.Services.AddHostedService<StatisticBackgroundService>();`

мне нужно что бы BackgroundServices сохранял каждый обьект statistic в бд

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и [*минимальный код*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58402965/6808809 А вообще, лучше разделить на разные сервисы и не трогать Background